Logarithms. Express $\log_3 5$ in terms of $p$ and $q$
How can I express $\log_3 5$ in terms of p and q whereby $$ p = \log_{10} 5 $$ and $$ q = \log_3 2 $$.
The given solution to this problem is $ \frac{pq}{(1 - p)} $.
Currently I'm stuck at the changing base and simplifying process. Here's the overview of what I've done.
$$\log_3 5$$
$$= \frac{\log_{10} 5}{\log_{10} 3}$$
$$= \frac{\log_{10} 5}{\frac{\log_3 3}{\log_3 10}}$$
$$= \log_{10} 5 \times \log_3 10$$
I tried plugging in the values of the given answer and indeed both $= \log_{10} 5 \times \log_3 10$ and  $ \frac{pq}{(1 - p)} $ gives the same answer.
Would appreciate if you could guide me through on how I should complete the simplification process.
Solution:
I was blinded by the recurring $log_3 5$.
It could be solved easily as pinpointed by @ultralegend5385.

Your work is very much on the right track. You can always try working backwards from the solution (also helps to check that the solution is actually valid) and go from there.

Hint: $$\log_3(10)=\log_3(2)+\log_3(5)$$

yes. I'm aware of this. But how should I proceed from here.
$$\log_3 5 = \log_{10}  5 * (\log_3 2 + \log_3 5)$$
$$\log_3 5 = pq + p* \log_3 5$$
there's the recurring $\log_3 5$

Solve for $\log_3(5)$ in that final line :)

@brucey: Take it to the other side. It is like solving for $x$ in $x=3+2x$.

$\log_3{5}=\log_{10}{5}\div\log_{10}{3}$
$\log_3{5}=\log_{10}{5}\times\log_3{10}$
$\log_3{5}=\log_{10}{5}\times(\log_3{2}+\log_{3}{5})$
$\log_3{5}=\log_{10}{5}\times\log_3{2}+\log_{10}{5}\times\log_{3}{5}$
$\log_3{5}-\log_{10}{5}\times\log_3{5}=\log_{10}{5}\times\log_3{2}$
$\log_3{5}(1-\log_{10}{5})=\log_{10}{5}\times\log_3{2}$
$\log_3{5}=\frac{\log_{10}{5}\times\log_3{2}}{1-\log_{10}{5}}$
$\log_3{5}=\frac{p\times q}{1-p}$
